# SQL IF EXIST problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to match a string var named "$ip" to a column name "ip" in "$Hood" table.
If there isn't a match then do something.

So I have this code:

```
if (mysql_query("IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1  1 FROM $Hood WHERE ip=$ip)") == 1)
```

And it's not working, it suppose to return 1 because there is a match.
What's wrong here?

Comment: why are you using `TOP 1` in the `SELECT` statement? and what is the type of the ip column in the DB?

Comment: TOP 1 is SQL Server TSQL.  MySQL I believe is LIMIT 1.

Comment: @Tom : then you should atleast enclose the `$ip` variable in single quotes since it is supposed to be a string. and try this query on for size: `SELECT IF(ip = '$ip',1,0) FROM $hood WHERE ip='$ip' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @BigFatBaby : This will return 1 record, but it could be ANY record in $hood, and whether that record matches with $ip, that's almost random. You at least need to specify an ORDER BY.

Comment: @Tom : this will select 1 if the `$ip` matches any ip in the table, and 0 otherwise... - was that not your intention?

Comment: @Dems : that is not entirely correct - the limit part of the query only limits the result set, it does not limit the search criteria. so the query will search the entire table, and will return only one row

Comment: @bigfatbaby : Apologies, the WHERE clause went in one eye and out of the other.  There still exists, however, another consideration.  The suggested query never returns 0 if no matches are found, instead it returns an empty record set; and these don't play nicely with equality operators.

Comment: @Dems : you are absolutely correct sir, i did not account for that... @Tom, i propose this then: mysql_num_rows(mysql_query(`SELECT ip FROM $hood WHERE ip='$ip' LIMIT 1`)) == 1`

Comment: @BigFatBaby : That seems the most elegant to me.

Comment: @Dems : well i will post it as an answer then for people to reference if they wish. thanks for the QA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply select the matching ip form the DB like so:

```
SELECT ip 
FROM $hood 
WHERE ip='$ip' 
LIMIT 1
```

and count the rows, if it is equal to 1 then you have a match, 0 otherwise, like so:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query(SELECT ip FROM $hood WHERE ip='$ip' LIMIT 1)) == 1)
```

Comment: Just needed to change the operator to not equal != and it worked perfectly :) Toda Raba!

Comment: @Tom : which shows you understand the principal behind it and not just copy/pasting - very well done!

Answer (score 1):

Mysql doesn't have top clause. You have to use limit

```
select * from table where condition
```

You can then use mysql_num_rows() to check result.

edit. Anothere alternative

```
select exists(select * from table where condition) as result
```

that gives you 1 or 0.

Comment: tried the seconde one, not working: if ((mysql_query("select exists(select * from $Hood where ip = '$ip') as result")) != 1) 
{

Comment: I prefer the first one anyway. `SELECT 1 FROM $Hood WHERE ip = '$ip' LIMIT 1`, then using mysql_num_rows() to check if you got 0 or 1 rows.

Answer (score 1):

If no matches are found, no records are returned.  You can't compare a NULL records set to '1' in this way.

Using COUNT is one option, but if the number of matches is very high, the following may yield performance benefits (at the cost of being longer winded)...

```
if (mysql_query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM $Hood WHERE ip=$ip) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END") != '1')
```

**EDIT**

On a side note, I'd advise a few debugging steps in understanding your problem...

Execute your query directly in SQL and see what the result is.  Once you're happy the SQL works, you know you now only have to deal with PHP.

Build the SQL query, and echo it to the screen.  Check that it's actually propperly formed, and test it directly in SQL again.  Now you know your PHP is building the query properly.

Now both build and execute the query in PHP, and echo the result to the screen.  Does the result match the behaviour when testing directly in SQL?

Finally, build this into the IF statement.

By validating each step you can quickly ascertain Where any issues lay and attack them directly.

Comment: I've editted my answer to add a note ab out possibly debugging steps.  It sounds as though the query isn't being build exactly as needed.  If you can establish the SQL logic works, and then check exactly what SQL is being generated by the PHP, you may find your bug.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql I think that your query should be

```
select ip from $Hood where ip = $ip limit 0, 1.
```

I also hope that you're escaping or validating your data.